# Creating a list style with enumitem

Tags: enumitem

I know it's possible with the `enumitem` package, to modify the list label to a custom format.
I've hacked together solutions to a couple of other questions I found on StackExchange to give me the 'solution' below.
Whilst it's the output I want, the code in the preamble is not very concise.

Is it possible do the same thing (or similar) using only the `\newlist` and `\setlist` commands from `enumitem` (and any other commands from `enumitem` I might need)?

[image: Result of compiling the code below]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\changeitem}{%
  \let\latexitem\item
  \renewcommand\item[1][]{\latexitem\relax{##1 --} }%
}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps]{label=\textit{Step \arabic*:},leftmargin=*}

\newenvironment{labelledsteps}[1][]
  {\begin{steps}[before=\changeitem,#1]}
  {\end{steps}}

\begin{document}

\begin{labelledsteps}
  \item[First Label]  First list item \newline
                      Still first list item
  \item[Second Label] Second list item
  \item[Third Label]  Third list item
\end{labelledsteps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should consider placing `\let\latexitem\item` in the preamble outside of the `\changeitem` macro.  That way, `\changeitem` will operate each time on the standard LaTeX `\item`.  As you have formulated it, each new `\changeitem` will be relative to the current definition of `\item`.

Comment: Why don't you just start from scratch?  All you need is \hangindent, \makebox and a counter.

Comment: I don't understand what the `labelledsteps` does with respect to steps, nor \changeitem, apart from adding an endash after t he label, which it would be as simple doing by hand and the label as ordinary text. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Yes @Bernard, it is!
I could do it manually, but for readability before compiling I think it's better to have it as a label.

Both the answers posted certainly give me the flexibility I was after.
Before I accept one though I would like to check that it actually is that case that this flexibility isn't present in the `enumitem` package then?
Specifically, I can't have a `#1` typed argument in the `\setlist` command when I'm setting the label text?

Comment: I thought of such a solution but didn't see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this code, using `xparse` and, incidentally, `xspace`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\newstep{o}{%
\item\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{#1 \textendash\xspace}}

\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps]{label=\textit{Step \arabic*:},leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{steps}
    \newstep[First Label] First list item \newline
                      Still first list item
    \newstep[Second Label] Second list item
    \newstep[Third Label] Third list item
    \newstep A Fourth list item without a label.
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using no packages.  The upside is that there is nothing you can't change.  The downside is that it is only one layer deep (no subitems).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newcounter{steps}

\newcommand{\step}[1][\empty]% #1 = label (optional)
{\stepcounter{steps}%
 \par
 \hangindent=4em
 \hangafter=1
 \makebox[4em][l]{\textit{Step \arabic{steps}:}}%
 \ifx#1\empty\else #1 --\fi
}
\newenvironment{labelledsteps}%
{\setcounter{steps}{0}%
 \let\item=\step
 \parskip=\baselineskip
 \parindent=0pt}%
{\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{labelledsteps}
  \item[First Label]  First list item \newline
                      Still first list item
  \item[Second Label] Second list item
  \item[Third Label]  Third list item
  \item No label
\end{labelledsteps}

\end{document}
```

[image: step item]

Answer (score 0):

Same output in a simple way without using `newlist` and `setlist` of course:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textit{Step \arabic*:}]
    \item First list item \newline
          Still first list item
    \item Second list item
    \item Third list item
    \item A Fourth list item without a label.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```